# I'm having trouble creating the file for my SIFT algorithm

Tags: python, pycharm, sift

I'm studying feature extraction and came across Scale-Invariant Feature Transform (SIFT) and I tried it in Pycharm

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('home.jpg')
gray= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

sift = cv2.SIFT()
kp = sift.detect(gray,None)

img=cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp)

cv2.imwrite('sift_keypoints.jpg',img)
```

The problem is I cannot find 'sift_keypoints.jpg' anywhere in my folders unless I comment out `kp = sift.detect(gray,None)` then the file is there.

What am I missing / doing wrong?

When I run the code here is the result:

```
...Recognition.py

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Comment: here's the link where i'm studying sift https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_sift_intro/py_sift_intro.html

Answer (score 0):

it seems my problem was that `sift = cv2.SIFT()` should be `sift = cv2.SIFT_create()`.
can anyone explain why that was the problem?
i really thought `kp = sift.detect(gray,none)` was the problem